# How do I get iTerm2's prompt to make marks when the prompt is Starship?

Tags: iterm2, fish, starship

I've run into a situation where installing [Starship](https://starship.rs) breaks the iTerm2 shell integration feature of making each prompt a "mark".

The only thing Terminal.app has that iTerm doesn't for me is jump to mark with <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd>. iTerm can do this with the shell integrations and <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd>.

But I have the fish shell and Starship and something just breaks about the mark's underlying ANSI code or whatever is used.

For completeness of context I can use `imgcat` or other shell extensions just fine.